# Plotting automatically updateable position vectors in Gnuplut by using arrows

Tags: gnuplot

I'm working with coordinate transformations in Matlab and I would like to plot some results in Gnuplot. The 3D location and orientation of the 4 coordinate systems of the given problem are known in terms of the inertial coordinate system.

I don't know how to display the 4 coordinate systems, so currently I am plotting only the origins of them (-> 4 singe points in a 3D graph).

**Im looking for help** by plotting the position vectors of these 4 points. This could be done by an arrow using the command "**set arrow**", which would point from the origin (0,0,0) of the 3D graph (inertial system) to the location of the current point (for example: 2,3,4).

However, if the Input values in the Matlab skript change, the locations of the origins also change and so the arrows (position vectors) are no longer pointing at the right spot.

Is there a way, how I could define the end point of an arrow in a more flexible way, so it always points at the current location according the the data-set from txt file?

Comment: `plot ... with vectors`